# "move" transition animation is not applied for top most item in Column, but for bottom most

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qtquick2

`move` transition animation is not applied for top most item in `Column`, when intermediate items are shown or become hidden. It is instead applied for bottom most item in spite of `Column` is aligned bottom.

Any alternative for applying animation for top most items?

```
Rectangle{
    width: 100
    height: 480
    MouseArea {
        id: mainMsA
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            console.log("clicked")
            showUsb2(visStatus)
            visStatus = !visStatus
        }
    }

    Column {
        id: statusColumn
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 20
        spacing: 8

        move: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "y"
                easing.type: Easing.Linear
            }
        }

        Image{
            id:usb1_st
            source:defines.statusBarUSB1
        }
        Image{
            id:usb2_st
            source:defines.statusBarUSB2
        }
        Image{
            id:usb3_st
            source:defines.statusBarUSB3
        }
    }
}
```

When `anchor` lines are commented the animation is smooth but when `anchor` lines are uncommented the animation is abrupt.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a minimal example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @jpnurmi ..hope this is clear